# State machine and network socket - how to handle race conditions

Tags: c#, state-machine

I am using Stateless in my C# network project, primarily as it is a nice way to add features such as wire level authorization after socket connection, delays for reconnection etc.

With that said, I am running into some race conditions and deadlocks of my own doing - reaching out for advise on best ways of dealing with this for the following states:

```
enum State { Stopped, Disconnected, Connecting, Connected, Resetting }
enum Trigger { Start, Stop, Connect, SetConnectComplete, Reset, SetResetComplete }

class StateMachine : StateMachine<State, Trigger>
{
    public StateMachine(Action OnDisconnected, Action OnConnecting, Action OnConnected, Action OnResetting) : base(State.Stopped)
    {
        this.Configure(State.Stopped)
            .Permit(Trigger.Start, State.Disconnected);

        this.Configure(State.Disconnected)
            .OnEntry(OnDisconnected)
            .Permit(Trigger.Connect, State.Connecting);

        this.Configure(State.Connecting)
            .OnEntry(OnConnecting)
            .Permit(Trigger.SetConnectComplete, State.Connected)
            .Permit(Trigger.Reset, State.Resetting);

        this.Configure(State.Connected)
            .OnEntry(OnConnected)
            .Permit(Trigger.Reset, State.Resetting);

        this.Configure(State.Resetting)
            .OnEntry(OnResetting)
            .Permit(Trigger.SetResetComplete, State.Disconnected);
    }
}
```

The functionality of this is where socket will automatically reconnect, and on connection start the receive loop. In the event of a socket error, it should go back to free up resources and then loop back around to start up again.

However when I dispose the object, the connected socket aborts, which also frees resources plus it tries waiting on itself.

I believe this is to do with the thread waiting on itself, so my design/state structure is definitely fundamentally off and appreciate pointers on better structure that would avoid deadlock entirely.

```
public class ManagedWebSocket : IDisposable
{
    readonly StateMachine stateMachine;
    Task backgroundReaderTask;

    private ClientWebSocket webSocket;
    private readonly ITargetBlock<byte[]> target;
    private readonly ILogger<ManagedWebSocket> logger;
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;
    bool isDisposing;

    public ManagedWebSocket(string uri, ITargetBlock<byte[]> target, ILogger<ManagedWebSocket> logger)
    {
        this.stateMachine = new StateMachine(OnDisconnected, OnConnecting, OnConnected, OnResetting);
        this.target = target;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    private void OnConnecting()
    {
        this.backgroundReaderTask = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            this.cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            this.webSocket = new ClientWebSocket();
            webSocket.Options.KeepAliveInterval = KeepAliveInterval;

            try
            {
                await this.webSocket.ConnectAsync(this.uri, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch(WebSocketException ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                await this.stateMachine.FireAsync(Trigger.Reset);
            }

            this.stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.SetConnectComplete);
        });
    }
    
    private void OnDisconnected()
    {
        if (isDisposing == false)
            this.stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Connect);
    }

    private void OnResetting()
    {
        FreeResources();
        this.stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.SetResetComplete);
    }

    private void OnConnected()
    {
        this.backgroundReaderTask = Task.Run( async () => {
            try
            {
                // returns when the internal frame loop completes with websocket close, or by throwing an exception
                await this.webSocket.ReceiveFramesLoopAsync(target.SendAsync, 2048, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            }

            await this.stateMachine.FireAsync(Trigger.Reset);
        });
    }

    public async Task SendAsync(byte[] data, WebSocketMessageType webSocketMessageType)
    {
        if (this.stateMachine.State != State.Connected)
            throw new Exception($"{nameof(ManagedWebSocket)} is not yet connected.");

        try
        {
            await webSocket
                    .SendAsChunksAsync(data, webSocketMessageType, 2048, this.cancellationTokenSource.Token)
                    .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(ex, ex.Message);
            await this.stateMachine.FireAsync(Trigger.Reset);
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        this.stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.Start);
    }    

    public void FreeResources()
    {
        this.logger.LogDebug($"{nameof(ManagedWebSocket.FreeResources)}");
        this.cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        this.backgroundReaderTask?.Wait();
        this.cancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        this.backgroundReaderTask?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (isDisposing)
            return;

        isDisposing = true;
        FreeResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using websocket?  Are you make an HTTP connection or a TCP connection?  A weboscket you only have one request and one response.  Doesn't make sense for a KeepAlive.

Comment: Yes this is by design per https://github.com/polygon-io/client-cs/blob/master/websocket_example/example.cs I need to subscribe, validate subscriptions etc hence looking into state machines

Comment: A websocket is HTTP and uses TCP as the transport level.  In Net managed library you do not have access to the TCP (the states you are using)  from the websocket.  A websocket you get one request and one response.  So you either get a response or you check for a timeout when you do not get a response.  If you want to TCP states then you would need a library that implements HTTP protocol using a TCP connection.

Comment: Thanks for.gbr replies jdweng, the websocket is most definetly a stream of data, per the link I sent, is streaming tens of thousands of individual messages per second. Seems our terminology maybe crossing wires, I use the underlying ClientWebSocket and it's get sent data in a stream. The other libraries such as the one in the link use the similair .net classes.

Comment: Are you getting a "Time Wait" error when you use Netstat?  A TCP connection should only get closed by one end of a connection.  There is a known race condition with TCP since the 1970s that is due to issues with the RFC specification.  When both ends of a TCP connection are simultaneously closed a race condition occurs.  TCP every command gets an ACK.  When both ends of connection close at same time one end doesn't get the ACK.  In windows you get a Time Wait status using Netstat.  Which means the connection is waiting for an ACK to the Close command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the deadlock is caused by calling `FreeResources();` in `OnResetting()`, since `FreeResources();` is waiting for `backgroundReaderTask` but within `backgroundReaderTask` you are awaiting `OnResetting()` via `await this.stateMachine.FireAsync(Trigger.Reset);`.

As some sort of workaround you could just omit the "await" keyword for triggering the reset, since it will dispose the entire object anyway.

Also note that there seems no reason for invoking `this.stateMachine.Fire(Trigger.SetConnectComplete);` if an exception was thrown previously in `OnConnecting()` - just move it into the try-block.

Additionally, as some sort of best-practice and side note, try following the [recommended dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose#code-try-4)

Comment: @jdweng in the comments of the question: A WebSocket is initiated via HTTP but is a protocol on top of TCP on its own. It is standardized in RFC 6455. And it does make perfectly sense to specify a keep-alive interval in the context of WebSockets, since a WebSocket connection is assumed "dead" when there is no communication for at least "keep-alive" period.